# How to add libraries with pip and conda to a Singularity container

Tags: pip, singularity-container

I'm working in a computational HPC node and I'm provided with a singularity container. I don't have write permissions to the image. I would like to execute this container, pip install some libraries and then save it as a different container image that I can access and full control in a later time. I check some of the tutorials but I'm confused on how to pip and build a new image.

Right now, when I do pip install a package, I got this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x2aaaad4a69d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/pyranges/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyranges (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyranges
```